# ANTLR4 TestRig (grun) throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception

Tags: java, antlr4, grun

I'm trying to learn ANTLR 4, and I'm following the examples given in *The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference*. Sadly I'm stuck at the first example.

---

System:
Windows 10 (1703)
Java 8, update 151
ANTLR 4, v4.7

My `%CLASSPATH%` is set as a system variable (`.;"D:\Program Files\Java\libs\antlr-4.7-complete.jar";`).
I have `antlr4.bat` and `grun.bat` available in my `%PATH%`, and I'm able to run `antlr4` from the command line.

`antlr4.bat` : `java -cp %CLASSPATH% org.antlr.v4.Tool %*`
`grun.bat` : `java -cp %CLASSPATH% org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig %*`

I'm using `-cp %CLASSPATH%` explicitly because I've seen a few others having problems when not using the `-cp` option.

---

My problem is this:
When I run `grun` on the example grammar `Hello` (`grun Hello r -tokens`) I get this error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloLexer (wrong name: main/resource/hello/HelloLexer)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.process(TestRig.java:129)
        at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.main(TestRig.java:119)
```

Any ideas to what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT:**
I thought I had found an answer. By `cd`-ing into the folder where the compiled files were (instead of calling `grun` from the root project folder) I managed to get through the example in question.

But when I tried to set up my own project, I came across the same issue, with the same error message as above.

This time, it seems like `grun` is complaining after I've run `antlr4` with the `-package` option.

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Wow... The solution was, of course, an easy solution... My problem was that I had `cd`'d to the root folder of my test project, and I just had to `cd` to (and call `grun` from) the directory where the compiled files are.</del>

<del>Edit:

It seems like I still have an issue with `grun`. See edited question.</del>

Edit2:
From what I can tell, `grun` doesn't cooperate very well with `antlr4`'s `-package` option.
So my solution was that I had to set up my project as a Gradle project, because apparently that works better.

Comment: Can you please specify what you mean by setting it up as a gradle project ?

Comment: Please be more specific on the answer.

Comment: Uhm.. i think this is definitely not the solution/answer lol. The problem is exactly as described by @Yifeng , which should be the actual marked answer

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem as you did. 
@DoTheGenes reminded me this may be caused by `@header {package com.blahblah.antlr4.hello;}` in your .g4 file. Grun has some unfixed bugs with package relocation command. When I removed this line with @header, the problem solved and I could run grun gui, tree and any other commands with generated and compiled files.
Hope this could help.

Comment: This is exactly the issue i had, no matter what i did it would never run using `grun`, only through code (which in hindsight is exactly because of that `@header` block in the grammar). From what i understood, `grun` was designed to work with everything in the SAME folder and WITHOUT a separate package folder, check my answer for an annoying but simple workaround (until grun gets fixed/updated).

Answer (score 0):

Try with fully qualifying the grammar name with the package it's part of, e.g.
com.demo.pl.Grammar. Seems to work with ANTLR 4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

I am using ANTLR 4.9.1 and i had the exact same issue. My project layout had a unique and separate location for :

- the grammar
- generated source files (location specified in the grammar by the `@header` block)

which made `grun` always fail (since everything has to be in the same folder). The workaround was to make another script that fixes these 2 `grun` bugs as such :

1. Move everything to 1 folder *(Fix first bug)*
2. Remove `@header{...}` from grammar *(Fix second bug)*
3. (Optional) If you don't have antlr in classpath then add it
4. Compile all `.java` files
5. Run `antlr4` (or `org.antlr.v4.Tool` manually) to generate parser `.java` files
6. Compile all parser `.java` files
7. Run `grun` (or `org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig` manually) with whatever option you want

The following `PowerShell` script shows how I've done it (keep in mind your paths might be different), in my case the language and project are called `Nameless` and i used the `.g4test` extension for test scripts (so adapt your `Bash`/`Batch`/`PowerShell` scripts accordingly)

```
# Script name : run.ps1
# Script arguments
param ($Target="-tokens")
# Options
$lang = "Nameless"
$startRule = "file"

# Paths
$antlr = "D:\Desktop\Workspaces\Java\ANTLRv4\antlr-4.9.1-complete.jar"
$project = "D:\Desktop\Workspaces\Java\Eclipse Workspace 2020\Nameless"
$javas = "$project\target\generated-sources\antlr4\generated"
$script = "$project\scripts\LiteralsTest.g4test"
$classes = "$project\build\classes\generated"

# Fix weird bug of TestRig needing all in 1 folder lol
Write-Host "Moving project files.." -NoNewLine
Copy-Item "$project\$lang.g4" -Destination $classes
Copy-Item -Path "$javas\*" -Destination $classes
cd $classes
Write-Host " done."

# Fix other framework bug that makes '@header' lines not run lol..
Write-Host "Removing package header line from grammar.." -NoNewline
(Get-Content -Path "$lang.g4" -Raw) -replace "(?sm)^@header`{.*?`}$" | Out-File -FilePath ".\$lang.g4" -Encoding ASCII
Write-Host " done."

# All should be good now, do the usual
Write-Host "Adding to classpath temporarily.." -NoNewLine
$env:CLASSPATH = ".;$antlr;$env:CLASSPATH"
Write-Host " done."

Write-Host "Generating Java files from grammar.." -NoNewLine
java -cp ".;$antlr" org.antlr.v4.Tool "$lang.g4" -listener -visitor
Write-Host " done."

Write-Host "Compiling java files.." -NoNewLine
javac -cp ".;$antlr" *.java
Write-Host " done."

Write-Host "Running.."
java -Xmx500M -cp ".:$env:CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig $lang $startRule $Target $script
```