# force ANTLR to generate the output files in a specific folder

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I don't like to have the ANTLR generated files in the same location as my `.g4` grammar and other version-controlled documents. I would like to put all the generated files in a separate nested folder that can be excluded via `.gitignore`. What I have tried so far is to create a folder `<someFolder>` inside the main folder and from inside that folder ran:

```
cd <someFolder>
antlr ../<grammarFile.g4>
```

however, it still spills all the generated files in the parent folder.

**P.S.** It shouldn't matter but my environment is macOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/tool-options.md:

> -o outdir
>
> ANTLR generates output files in the current directory by default. This option specifies the output directory where ANTLR should generate parsers, listeners, visitors, and tokens files.

in the example above, from the main folder run

```
antlr <grammarFile.g4> -o <someFolder>
```

Comment: Additional note: if you run the antlr4 jar with a path to your grammar(s) (not using a grammar in the same folder) it will recreate the same folder path structure in the output dir (a reminiscence to Java where bundles are represented by folders). If you don't want that use the additional parameter `-Xexact-output-dir`

Comment: @MikeLischke do you think that's the reason I'm stuck with [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66942445/4999991)?

Comment: I can't say, as I'm not using Java that much.

Comment: @MikeLischke I followed your instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66957324/4999991) and ran it on the results from this page, but I get [these error messages](https://pastebin.com/MR1Y9XNQ). I tried the `-packge` option from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121549/antlr4-testrig-grun-throws-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-exception), but it didn't work.

Comment: @MikeLischke Thanks a lot! -Xexact-output-dir is exactly what i'm looking for!