# TestRig / grun drops java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using the output directory -o option

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66940875/4999991), I am using the following steps to compile the parser/lexer from [this repository](https://github.com/AltElmer/ElmerSolverParser):

```
export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/Cellar/antlr/<version>/antlr-<version>-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"
antlr <grammarName>.g4 -o <someFolder>/
javac <someFolder>/<grammarName>*.java
```

but when I use the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66957324/4999991):

```
grun <someFolder>/<grammarName> tokens -tokens < <inputFile>
```

I get this error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IllegalName: <someFolder>/<grammarName>Lexer
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:889)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1014)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:825)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:723)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:646)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:604)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.process(TestRig.java:129)
    at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.main(TestRig.java:119)
```

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see where you’ve specified a package name, so now your Java classes are located in <someFolder>.  Be sure to compile them in that folder.

Then you’ll need to add that folder to your classpath (probably instead of “.”)

Try adding <someFolder> into the CLASSPATH you’re exporting.  Then leave it off of your grun command line.

Java will only load classes from the Classpath (it’s a security thing). When TestRig runs, it attempts to load your class by building the Java class name it would have produced for you Parser (and Java will have to find that class somewhere in the classpath).

Your *could* modify the `grun` alias to allow for you to specify a directory to search for your classes, and use the `-cp` option on the Java command, but that’s probably more trouble than just adding it to you classpath that you’re using for this testing.

Comment: so it should be like `export CLASSPATH="./<someFolder>:/usr/local...`

Comment: Do you have *.class files in your <someFolder>?  They should be there from compiling the *.java files that ANTLR put there.  Also, you should NOT specify that folder when you run grun.